# Why is checkbox in knockoutJs written to only when checked?

Tags: knockout.js

I'm using a special extended version of Ko which uses a commit()/peek() type functions on a dependant observable so that I only save the data onto the form if it is committed to the database (on Ok) and reverted on cancel.

Problem I'm having is that when I check a checkbox, the write function is called correctly on the protected observable. However, if I uncheck the checkbox, the write function isn't called, so when the model is sent to my MVC controller, the checkbox boolean is still TRUE.

Why is knockout not writing the FALSE value?

**UPDATED QUESTION WITH CODE:**

Please see this JsFiddle here to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/b2Qu2/3/

***Minor issue***

Note that there is 1 other problem with the demo - for some reason, when I check/uncheck the checkbox, the peeked value is not updated on the UI even though it is chained to a dependentObservable.  You can still peek the value by clicking the 'peek' button.

***Major Issue***

To reproduce problem:

```
1) Click 'peek' button: Shows FALSE - CORRECT

2) Check IsAdmin checkbox

3) Click 'peek' again: Shows TRUE - CORRECT

4) Uncheck IsAdmin

5) Click 'peek' again: SHOWS TRUE - INCORRECT!!
```

**Example scenario**

Imagine a dialog is shown with a checkbox for an Admin user. Only 1 admin user can be set, and the server responds with valid/invalid if an admin user already exists.
The user then unchecks the checkbox, but now the viewmodel thinks the checkbox is ALWAYS true?? Reason for using the protectedObservable is if the server response succeeds, the commit() method is called so everything is persisted on the UI. If the user cancels the dialog or an error occurs, the original values are not overwritten.

Comment: Can you share more of your code, as far as how it is bound/used?

Comment: @RP Niemeyer - I've updated my question with some code. Struggling with this one!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that the write is only firing on one value is because it will only trigger when it believes that it needs to write a different value to what it is bound against.  So, the actual value of your protectedObservable is not changing.  If it is true and you try to set it to true, then the write does not fire, since it believes that it has the correct value.

I would probably change it up a bit and use something like this:

```
ko.protectedObservable = function (initialValue) {
    //private variables
    var _actual = ko.observable(initialValue),
        _temp = ko.observable(initialValue);

    //access to temp value
    _actual.temp = _temp;

    //commit the temporary value to our observable, if it is different
    _actual.commit = function () {        
        if (_temp() !== _actual()) {
            _actual(_temp());
        }
    };

    //notify subscribers to update their value with the original
    _actual.reset = function () {
        _actual.valueHasMutated();
        _temp(_actual());
    };

    return _actual;
};
```

With this version you can bind against `field1` or `field1.temp`.  You don't need a peek even, because both the temp and actual values are observable.

It would look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/BwDYE/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code example. My whole code-base is based on the protectedObservable based on my first fiddle so not sure I want to change its behaviour/bindings.   The bindings on the model use the actual protectedObservables rather than .temps.  Your example is based on a reset() if the dialog box is cancelled out/server error and commit() on success. My model is based on the inverse, if user cancels out, or server error then do nothing as the peeked values are used to send to the server. If server succeeds, then commit(). Mmm, not sure how to get round this...

Comment: I'm not sure I quite follow how it is different.  Just bind everything to `yourfield.temp` instead of `yourfield`.  Should work out the same.  Maybe you can help me understand better how it does not work in your scenario?  Would be happy to help come up with a suitable alternative.

Comment: Is there any way to ensure that the checkbox depedentObservable value is always written to regardless of whether it has changed from its original value. It seems that this is the problem and ties in with your original answer. I put debug statements in the write function on my original code, and it only gets called when the checkbox value is opposite to its original value which is no good, as the peeked value won't be updated. If this can be fixed I won't need to replace all my views with .temps. Hope this makes sense! Let me know what you think is the best way forward.

Comment: I think that I would switch to using the .temp observables.  The bindings expect that when you check the checkbox that it directly (observable) or indirectly (writeable dependentObservable) changes the value that the `checked` binding is bound against.  You could replace the `checked` binding with a modified copy of it, but that is generally not a good idea.  To do this you would want to look for the line that says `if (modelValue() !== valueToWrite) {
                    modelValue(valueToWrite);
                }` and remove the `if` statement and always write the value.

Comment: Hi, I have implemented your suggestion and it works quite well now. My KoHelpers now write binding attibutes with .temp appended to it and this does the trick, albeit with some other minor changes. I've noticed though that a d.o. tracks changes to a textbox (e.g. adding 1 then removing 1) but not to a checkbox going back to false after clicking false/true/false. Am I right in saying this?

Comment: The `checked` binding does not write a value, if it is the same.  The `value' binding always writes the user's input.